# How to highlight cells which are the first of the alphabet letter in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

How to highlight the word if it is the first of the alphabet?

## EXAMPLE

```
aaple   **highlight this
arrow
asterisk
banana  **highlight this
banter
bow
cat     **highlight this
citrus
cow
dog     **highlight this
donkey


NOTE: There are multiple columns and all the values are sorted already


Maximum number of highlighted words = 26

How to do this is google sheet?
```

## Question

- How to highlight only the words which are the first in their alphabet

Example google sheet which should be highlighted is given below:

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NzbtJhQj4hQBnZXcmwise3bLBIAWrE0qwSus_bz7a0/edit#gid=207581865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following formula in conditional formatting:

```
=AND((ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(SORT(FLATTEN($A$1:$F$55),1,1),LEFT(SORT(FLATTEN($A$1:$F$55),1,1),1)=LEFT(A1,1)),1,1)=A1),(A1<>""))
```

Only if the first names are repeated, then all of them will be highlighted.

[image]